# How to find all $F[X]$-submodules of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ denote the linear transformation that is the projection onto the line $y=2x$. List all $F[X]$-submodules of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (where the $F[X]$-module structure here is determined by $T$.)

So if $f(x) = a_{0}+\cdots+a_{n}x^{n}$, we define scalar multiplication as follows:
$$
f(x) \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ \end{bmatrix} 
= a_{0} \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ \end{bmatrix} 
+ a_{1}T\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ \end{bmatrix} 
+ \cdots 
+ a_{n}T^{n}\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

Using orthogonal projection we have the following:
$$
f(x) \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ \end{bmatrix} 
= a_{0}\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ \end{bmatrix} 
+ a_{1}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{x+2y}{5}\\ \frac{2x+4y}{5}\\ \end{bmatrix} 
+ \cdots 
+ a_{n}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{x+2y}{5}\\ \frac{2x+4y}{5}\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

So this is the scalar multiplication of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an $F[x]$-module. But now the question is what do all submodules look like? I know that submodules are closed under addition and scalar multiplication, where the scalar multiplication looks as I've described, but I'm having a hard time listing out the specifics of the spaces. Any hints/suggestions for tackling this are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Express $\mathbb R^2$ in terms of eigenvectors for $T$.

Comment: Another way of thinking about the module action: since projection is idempotent, i.e. $T^2 = T$, it's equivalent to think about $\pi(X)$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $\pi: F[x] \twoheadrightarrow F[X]/(X^2 - X)$ is the canonical projection onto the quotient.

Comment: What is $F$ in your $F[X]$? (and later: $F[x]$) Don't you rather mean $\Bbb R[X]$?

Comment: Use that (for any linear map $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$) the $\Bbb R[X]$ sub-modules are merely those linear subspaces $V\subset\Bbb R^2$ such that $T(V)\subset V.$